# PHP Insert into PostgreSQL

Tags: php, string, postgresql

So it's probably a really stupid/basic question, but i have this simple PHP function (which works) and inserts data into a PostgreSQL DB.

My issue is when it encounters specific data;

```
function insertData($pg, $csvfile)
      {
        $x = 0;
        foreach ($csvfile as $data)
        {
          $email = $csvfile[$x]['email'];
          $name = $csvfile[$x]['name'];
          $surname = $csvfile[$x]['surname'];
          $query = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, surname) VALUES ('$email', '$name', '$surname')";
          $result = pg_query($pg, $query);
          $x++;
        }
      }
```

And while this works, it falls over with a surname such as:

> O'hare

And obviously this occurs because then the PHP code comes out as:

> ...VALUES ('john@example.com', 'John', 'O'hare')";

but im not sure of how i should be structuring the PHP to allow for this.

Comment: Using PDO statement you resolve your problem's [http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function insertData($pg, $csvfile) {
    $nbr = count(file($csvfile));   
    for($i=0; $i<$nbr; $i++) {
      $email = pg_escape_string( $csvfile[$i]['email'] );
      $name = pg_escape_string( $csvfile[$i]['name'] );
      $surname = pg_escape_string( $csvfile[$i]['surname'] );
      $query = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, surname) VALUES ('$email', '$name', '$surname')";
      $result = pg_query($pg, $query);
      if (!$result) {
        echo "Error while executing the query: " . $query;
        exit;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would pg_escape_string the email too, just by principle.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the string parameters. And it is much better if you can use PDO extension, because `prepared statements` can take care of escaping for you and also helps with preventing SQL injection and some other security concerns.

```php
function insertData(PDO $dbh, $csvfile) {
    $x = 0;
    foreach ($csvfile as $data)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, surname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $params = [
             $csvfile[$x]['email'],
             $csvfile[$x]['name'],
             $csvfile[$x]['surname']
        ];
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        $x++;
    }
}
```

- [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion as to using PDO;
I hadn't used PostgreSQL before writing this small app, and im under a tight deadline & don't have time to change the rest of the app to use PDO at this stage.

Comment: The $params are not used anywhere? This can't work. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Solution using prepared query

```
function insertData($dbname, $tbname, $csvfile)
{
  $result = [];
  // Connect to a database named "mary"
  $dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=$dbname");

  // Prepare a query for execution
  $result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_query", 'INSERT INTO $1 (email, name, surname) VALUES ($2, $3, $4)');

 // Execute the prepared query.  Note that it is not necessary to escape

  foreach ($csvfile as $data)
  {
    $email = $data['email'];
    $name = $data['name'];
    $surname = $data['surname'];
    $query = "";
    $result[] = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", array($tbname, $email, $name, $surname));
   }
  if (in_array(false, $result) )
     return false;
  else
     return true;
}
$dbname = "your dbname";
$tbname = "name of table";
$csvFile = [];
if (insertData($dbname, $tbname, $csvFile))
  echo "Data inserted";
else
   echo "Data not inserted";
```

Answer (score 0):

So i took note of the suggestions from @Karsten Koop and @TOH19, and came up with this code which is working;

```
function insertData($pg, $csvfile)
      {
        $x = 0;
        foreach ($csvfile as $data)
        {
          $email = pg_escape_string($csvfile[$x]['email']);
          $name = pg_escape_string($csvfile[$x]['name']);
          $surname = pg_escape_string($csvfile[$x]['surname']);
          $query = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, surname) VALUES ('".$email."', '".$name."', '".$surname."')";
          $result = pg_query($pg, $query);
          $x++;
        }
      }
```